# Calling up a def: function in an IF statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

It's been a while since I used python (been studying CISCO IOS) so I'm bit rusty.  I have forgotten how to assign a function to an IF statement.

```
import ipaddress

q1= input("Please enter 'network' to calculate an IP address range, or enter 'port' to scan an ip address for open ports  ")
if (q1 == str(network)):
    networkclac()
if (q1 == str(port)):
    portscan()


def networkclac():
    try:
        network = input('please input network address: ')
        network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
        print(network)

    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a network address')

    iplist= list(ipaddress.ip_network(network).hosts())
    for i in range(10,len(iplist),2):
        print(iplist[i])

#def portscan():
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shane\PycharmProjects\RodCertIV\ITCNWK409.py", line 4, in <module>
    if (q1 == str(network)):
NameError: name 'network' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The aim of the program is to calculate a range of IP addresses, and scan ip addresses for open ports.

I have created the code for the IP Calculator, but I have forgotten how to call up a function in an IF statement.

I want the program, to ask the user if they wish to calculate an IP network address or run a port scan. If the end user inputs "network" I want the program to run the **def network clac(): function**

*It's something quite simple that I'm missing, this should be an easy question for some.*

**EDIT
I HAVE SLOVED THIS ISSUE WITH ASSISTANCE FROM THIS COMMUNITY, I POST UPDATED CODE BELOW**

```
import ipaddress

def f1():
    try:
        network = input('please input network address with the prefix: ')
        network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
        print(network)

    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a network address')

    iplist= list(ipaddress.ip_network(network).hosts())
    for i in range(10,len(iplist),2):
        print(iplist[i])

#def portscan():

print("Please enter 'network' to calculate an IP address range")
print("Please enter 'port' to scan for open ports")

q1= input("please input your choice:  ")
if q1 == "network":
    f1()
#if q1 == "port":
    #f2()
```

Now, I will work on the port scan function and ultimately convert this in to a GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `str(network)` with `"network"` and `str(port)` with `"port"` should work.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shane\PycharmProjects\RodCertIV\ITCNWK409.py", line 5, in <module>
    networkclac()
NameError: name 'networkclac' is not defined

Comment: now receiving error that networkclac() is not defined

Comment: I guess you'll have to define the function above the q1 input. Now when it is called, the function called networkclac() is yet to be defined.

Comment: Yes, I just worked out that was the problem. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by coding the user input section after the def function. *I.e. The computer reads the def function before it reads the user input function*

```
import ipaddress

def f1():
    try:
        network = input('please input network address: ')
        network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
        print(network)

    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a network address')

    iplist= list(ipaddress.ip_network(network).hosts())
    for i in range(10,len(iplist),2):
        print(iplist[i])

#def portscan():


q1= input("Please enter 'network' (with prefix) to calculate an IP address range, or enter 'port' to scan an ip address for open ports  ")
if q1 == "network":
    f1()
#if q1 == "port":
    #f2()
```